# how to create a line break in php using "\n"?

Tags: php

I am very new in PHP programming and my line break does not working.

Please find the bug, in the below code:

```
<?php
echo "hello World \n ";
//the next section will demonstrate the use of variable
$name='Nadim Emon';
echo "Hello $name";
?>
```

Comment: New line breaks `\n` only appear as new lines when writing to files. Either use `<br>` or `nl2br` as provided from the answers given below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working code, direct use this code it will work

```
<?php
//the next section will demonstrate the use of variable
$name='Nadim Emon';
echo nl2br("hello World.\nHello $name.");
?>
```

Comment: Its my pleasure :) @user3501484

Answer (score 0):

The line break works fine, but the browser displays HTML entities, not line breaks.

Change your code to this:

```
<?php
echo "hello World <br> ";
//the next section will demonstrate the use of variable
$name='Nadim Emon';
echo "Hello $name";
?>
```

Browsers display code that has specific values and generally ignores whitespace. You can get around this by using some very specific HTML tags such as `<pre>` which will then maintain line breaks in your output.

There is also another option such as PHP's [nl2br](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) which will then replace any line breaks with HTML code to place line breaks in as you expect them to be displayed by a browser.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `<br/>` tag

```
 <?php
    echo "hello World"."<br/>";
    //the next section will demonstrate the use of variable
    $name='Nadim Emon';
    echo "Hello $name";
    ?>
```